# Reading DateField with specific format from SQL database using peewee

Tags: python, peewee, datefield

I would like to read a column of date from SQL database. However, the format of the date in the database is something like `27-Jan-13` which is `day-month-year`. When I read this column using peewee DateField it is read in a format which cannot be compared later using `datetime.date`.

Can anyone help me solve the issue?

Comment: I have not used peewee. But y not convert string to datetime format ?

Comment: @ Thothadri Thanks. Your suggestion works well in general when I do not use peewee. I made a mistake in the question saying that it is read as a string. Now, I edited that part. The problem still remains when using peewee

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data in the database using the format %Y-%m-%d. When you extract the data you can present it in any format you like, but to ensure the data is sorted correctly (and recognized by SQLite as a date) you must use the %Y-%m-%d format (or unix timestamps if you prefer that way).